# Group components with layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to have my chart side by side with my other components.

Iv tried so many hours with different layouts but I cant get it to be side by side. 
My idea was to group all components except the chart in one layout and the chart in another, then just put them side by side. But I cant get it to work.

This is how it looks now:
[image]

With the code as of now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChartLineLayout"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:thumbTint="@color/orange"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pieChartLineLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:thumbTint="@color/red"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:thumbTint="@color/blue"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="0%"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_orange"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Carbohydrates"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="0%"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_reds"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Proteins"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="0%"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Fats"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

User `LinearLayout` as your container (with horizontal orientation). Then add pie chart to it and another, vertical `LinearLayout` with seek bars in it.